# exception handling while using django and django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, exception

While using django and django rest framework and strictly using the frame work code.

Example,

using a router connected to a view set to a serializer into a model.

What I mean is no custom code, other than what is required to feed into the django rest frameworks code, do we not need exceptions?

I ask because in all the code examples I have seen, I have yet to see a try catch block.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there will be some type of error thrown if the data is in the incorrect format or doesn't contain correct values such as a wrong data type or invalid primary key on some request. The Django REST Framework serializers take care of these kinds of errors by raising `ValidationError`s and keeping track of errors in `serializer.Serializer._errors`. The DRF framework presents these errors back to the user in a suitable format, for example:

```
{"detail": "Method 'DELETE' not allowed."}
```

when a user tried to send a HTTP DELETE request. More information on how DRF handles different exceptions can be found [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/).

As for code that you write yourself within views, serializers, models etc. that is up to you to try/except and handle however you deem necessary. Often in a serializer, you might use `raise ValidationError(yourError)` and in a view you might `return Response(yourError, status=400)`.

Hope I've helped.